# How To Send DropDown Menu In Java Discord API?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I Am Making A Bot In Java Discord API,
I want to send a Drop Down Menu In A Channel,
There is a MessageChannel Object I Have and I Know How To Send Message By
 `channel.sendMessage("MESSAGE").queue();`
But How I Send A Drop Down Menu?

I Have Tried,

1. Making A Class Implementing SelectMenu Interface,
   i have overrided all the necessary methods like `getMinValue()`, `getPlaceHolder()`
   I Have Expected,
   I My Bot Will Send A Drop Down Menu, in a text channel and when I select an option it will send me some result in that channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the latest version of JDA (5.0.0-beta.2), the way to send a select menu is this:

1. Create a `StringSelectMenu` to allow selecting arbitrary strings:

   ```java
   // The string here is the id later used to identify the menu on use. Make it unique for each menu.
   StringSelectMenu.Builder builder = StringSelectMenu.create("menu:id");
   // Add one or more options
   // First parameter is the label that the user will see, the second is the value your bot will receive when this is selected.
   builder.addOption("Hello World", "hello_world");
   // Then once you have configured all you want, build it
   StringSelectMenu menu = builder.build();
   ```
2. Send the menu using one of the send methods (reply/sendMessage)

   ```java
   // ActionRow is the layout in which your component is arranged (this is currently the only available layout)
   channel.sendMessageComponents(ActionRow.of(menu)).queue();
   ```
3. Setup an event listener for this menu

   ```java
   public void Listener extends ListenerAdapter {
       @Override
       public void onStringSelectInteraction(StringSelectInteractionEvent event) {
           // same id as before in create(...)
           if (event.getComponentId().equals("menu:id")) {
               List<String> selected = event.getValues(); // the values the user selected
               ... your code to handle the selection ...
               // Either reply with a message
               event.reply("Your selection was processed").queue();
               // Or by editing the message (replace means it removes the menu)
               event.editMessage("It was selected").setReplace(true).queue();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

There is also `EntitySelectMenu` which works rather similarly, but can be used to select `User`/`Member`/`Role` or `GuildChannel` instead of string options.